# What is the purpose of launch images in an iOS application?

Tags: ios, xcode

How important is it to add Launch Images to an iOS application? I assume that these are like a cached file to show on the screen while the application is getting setup, when there might otherwise be nothing to show until it is fully running. Is this right?

If so, what should a launch image be if your app might start in different states, or does this not effect return to foreground when multitasking? If it is only for the very first initial launch of the app, then the launch image should just be the same as whatever graphic normally appears when you first start the app, right?

Apple must not care too much about whether your app actually includes these, since mine never have.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downgraded. It seems a fair inquiry for anyone new to Xcode or iOS development, and my question is clear.

Comment: I think the problem here came from the fact that you never specified what platform this was for.  Xcode is merely an IDE, and can be used to develop Mac and iOS applications, so it was hard to decipher what you were referring to.  I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question could be found from searching or even experienced when developing an app on the simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:  as Zev mentions below, the Apple HIG recommendation has changed since I originally answered this question.  Apple now recommends that you take all of the static elements of your first screen and make that into your default or launch page.  All dynamic elements are to be removed, to give the impression that your app is going through an initialization process -- which in some cases may mean that your default screen is simply a background from your app.  Thanks to Zev Eisenberg for pointing that out, "splash" pages are not recommended.

The launch image will show while your app is initializing, it's a good idea to have one.  If you don't have one the user is likely to stare at a blank screen while waiting for your app to load.  I believe the recommendation is to use an image that looks like the first page of your app.  Here is the reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5

Comment: thanks for answering, even despite all the unexpected down votes on this question.

Comment: In the document you link, Apple discourages against making a splash screen. If you use an image of the UI, partially loaded, it will make your app seem like it is loading faster than it really is. Look at Apple Notes, for example. The UI seems to load in stages, which you perceive as faster than looking at a blank screen until it is fully loaded. A splash screen defeats the purpose of this illusory “faster” loading.

Comment: I find this is a very valid question. Thanks for asking.

Comment: My question is what if the app wants to show a different first screen on first launch than later launches? (I don't mean foregrounding here, but relaunching).

Comment: @Alan Moore  is it ok to have just one launch image say LaunchImage@3x.png in your project, will apple reject my app because of not providing other configuration images, the reason why I wanna do is because my image is of around 25 KB.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad -- yes, in my experience you can't publish an app with only one image.  It depends on what devices and iOS versions you are supporting as to which ones you need.

Answer (score 0):

how about if app is starting immediately and no time passed ?
what if you see (or cannot see) for a 0.1 sec launch image ?
would it be still useful to have two images in main bundle that will never be seen or used ?

Comment: the launch images should look just like your interface so even if they show for a fraction of a second, which they often will during app launch, etc, then there is no visible change between them and the actual interface